# Reading a file from /etc/designs in java

Tags: aem, jcr

I'm in need of storing a string in JCR that'll be used in an OSGi bundle(so that it can be modified as needed in CRXde)
I have stored my string at the location `/etc/designs/shc/components/linkcheck/regex.txt/jcr:content`, where `regex.txt` is the file that contains my regex string.

I'm using the following code to read that String in a bundle but with no luck. It is throwing `NullPointerException` at `resourceResolver.getResource`

```
Resource dataResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/etc/designs/shc/components/linkcheck/regex.txt/jcr:content"); 
Node node = dataResource.adaptTo(Node.class);
String regex = node.getProperty("jcr:data").getValue().toString();
```

`regex.txt` is of type `nt:file` and the data is visible in CRXde but the code fails.

Any direction will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

this should work-

```
Resource dataResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/etc/designs/shc/components/linkcheck/regex.txt"); 
Node jcnode = dataResource.adaptTo(Node.class).getNode("jcr:content");
InputStream is = jcnode.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();String line;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
            //do something
}
//do whatever with sb
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the NullPointerException is thrown at resourceResolver.getResource(...), please check the resourceResolver is not null.